# Android UI Design and Layout Adjustment with DP unit

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working for build the UI of my team's App. 
In the beginning, my partner designs UI using Sketch 3.
According to the Android API guide for development Supporting Multiple Screens
 we known that **1dp = 1px in mdpi**.
So we plan to design a basic standard UI in mdpi density. Other density would be automatically fit the position or length if we use dp as our length unit.

The basic UI resolution for designing canvas we use in Sketch is 360 x 640. We've read some articles, some articles said the mdpi resolution for designing standard is 360 x 640, and others said is 480 x 320.
It's really confused. We finally choose 360 x 640, because 480 x 320 is 4:3 aspect ratio not so many Android devices use it.

After we've done our UI, I'm trying to apply it to our app. But I've met some problems with positioning element. For example, our splash page.
Here is our splash page, I can hold Option/Alt to get the distance between edge to out element in Sketch 3. Because the UI sample file was made in mdpi resolution, I can use the length directly.(1px = 1dp in mdpi)
[Splash Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLDP8.png)

CoolLogo is a ImageView. the whole layout is an RelativeLayout.
I'm using `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to make ImageView in the center of Layout.
and `android:layout_marginTop="268dp"` to make it right position according to our UI sample file.

Here is whole layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/LaunchPageLayout">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/coollogo"
    android:layout_marginTop="268dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Preview on the Nexus 5(5", xxdpi, 1080 x 1920) looks fine. But the ImageView position seems to be incorrect a little bit.

When switch to smaller device such as Nexus One(3.7", hdpi, 480 x 800), the position is totally wrong. it should be in more upside position.
[Nexus One Preview Sample Image in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B04H6.png)

I'm confused. How can we get the right position values when we put our element into layout? Doesn't it means we just only to design a UI in mdpi it should fit all density? but if that is ture, why the layout on small devices is wrong? because our sample UI is design in mdpi resolution. I'm totally muddled.

might somebody give me some advices or some best practice to bulid UI?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to guideline,
Google is not recommend to use absolutely pixel unit to design UI. 
We use the method below to design our application in the end. 
Share to everybody who started to design Android UI.

Basically, we need an **mdpi** size canvas, the canvas size is `320px * 480px` 
We use this resolution as our standard resolution, 
including measuring length and size.

And if you ever heard about the design of iOS UI (or macOS).
You'll know that iOS often use `320px * 480px` as standard **x1** resolution. 
When export resources, there will be **x1** for standard resolution and **x2** for Retina resolution.
 
Because the Retina resolution is two times of standard resolution.

Just like that, if we use standard resolution, Android will help us to fit on machines with different resolutions. 
so we got:

```
mdpi   => x1  (the standard)
hdpi   => x1.5
xhdpi  => x2
xxhdpi => x3
```

Theoretically, if we follow standard resolution, we can build layout for any other resolution. 
By the way, We can set different dimen values as well. 
it will help the layout to be more accurate in visually. 
Maybe the best way to build one layout to fit all kind of resolution currently is to use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html).

but this kind of approach sometimes doesn't make sense. 
Anyway, designing UI for phone and tablet (or even phablet) always be a good user experience.